# objective c method to return a dynamic type

Tags: objective-c

I have many child-entities which inherit properties from the same BaseEntity.

I would like to write a generic method which accepts any of the children and sets the base properties.

```
ChildDto *child = [[ChildDto alloc] init];
child = [BaseEntityDto SetBaseProperties:child fromDictionary:src];
```

The above gives the 'incompatible pointer type' error.

When I try casting the resulting BaseEntity to one of it's child classes, the cast fails and the object remains of type BaseEntity.

```
child = (ChildDto*)[BaseEntityDto SetBaseProperties:child fromDictionary:src];
```

Apparently casting is a bad idea in Objective C due to the use of pointers and there appears to be no 'dynamic' type to set as the return type.

So what's the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think what you are doing should work; show some code please.

Comment: If all child classes are from same base entity and you want to set only base properties create a method which accepts base entity class as a parameter.

Comment: Coming from c# the above makes perfect sense to me.  But it doesn't work - added some code to help explain.

Comment: What's the return type of the `SetBaseProperties` method?  If it's `BaseEntityDto` or some other superclass of `ChildDto` then you need to cast to the subclass.  The same would be true in C#, Java, and C++.  If `SetBaseProperties` doesn't actually return an instance of `ChildDto` then you have other problems.

Comment: SetBaseProperties returns a BaseEntity - but the cast to a child fails to change the instance type

Comment: @nugget: One quick clarification on the casting-- a cast will never *change* the type of something. An object remains whatever type it is when created. Casts are used, on occasion, to clarify to the compiler what something should be treated as when it might be ambiguous or you're doing something a little clever. But that's only a bit of syntax; a cast won't actually alter the object.

Comment: Thanks Ben. A lesson learnt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no reason not to do so, you should use plain inheritance to create the objects

```
@interface BaseEntity : NSObject
-(instancetype)initWithProperties:(NSDictionary *) properties;
@end


@implementation BaseEntity

-(instancetype)initWithProperties:(NSDictionary *) properties
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
         // apply properties for base
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@interface ChildDTO : BaseEntity
@end


@implementation ChildDTO

-(instancetype)initWithProperties:(NSDictionary *) properties
{
    self = [super initWithProperties:properties];
    if (self){
         // apply properties for child
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I was just typing out something similar after I read your comment above and you beat me to it :)  That is much cleaner.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is very dynamic. Your issues may come from a lack of experience. I suggest you get familiar with the Key-Value Coding Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html. It has a good chance to provide the answer to your question.

Comment: Yep, you are correct in that ObjC is new to me :) That looks like a nice read - but was hoping for a quick pointer to get me past this hurdle for the night.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I pass in a child of BaseEntity to SetBaseProperties, set the props and return nothing, it works.

```
ChildDto *child = [[ChildDto alloc] init];
[BaseEntityDto SetBaseProperties:child fromDictionary:src];
// base properties of child are now set
```

So the signature for SetBaseProperties is:

```
+(void)SetBaseProperties:(BaseEntityDto *)object fromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
```

Is that a correct way of doing it?

Comment: Why don't you just let `BaseEntity` have a `-initWithProperties:`, set the base properties there and override it for setting chilled properties in`ChildeDto` and call the Base implementation from there?